# Comparing Time Strings

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have 2 times that create a time range that a map annotation is visible(a start time and an end time).  Whenever the current time is greater than the end time, the annotation is removed. The user inputs the times as a string then I add that time string to the current date string, then I convert the date as "h:mm a, M/dd/yyyy" into an actual date.  The problem I am having is that if someone says the event starts at night (PM) then ends in the early morning or something (AM) then the event annotation is instantly removed because it creates the end time as AM time of the day that is about to end instead of the new day.  Here is my current method for getting the time strings in code:

```
let SpotStartTime = StartTimeTextField.text;
    let SpotEndTime = EndTimeTextField.text;

    let date = NSDate();
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
    formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy";

    let Date = formatter.stringFromDate(date)

    let EndTime = SpotEndTime;



    let RealEndTime = (EndTime! + ", " + Date);
    print(RealEndTime);
```

then I convert this string into a date using this method:

```
let TimeStr = EndTime

   let dateFormater : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   dateFormater.dateFormat = "h:mm a, M/dd/yyyy
   let EndDate = (dateFormater.dateFromString(TimeStr))

          let realEnd = EndDate
```

How do I modify this so that I can compare the StartTimeTextField to the EndTimeTextField?  I need something that basically compares the two and if the StartTimeTextField has "PM" in it and the EndTimeTextField has "AM" in it then the EndTime gets 24 hours added to it, but I don't know how to do this in code. 
Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I understood what you want to do, I come up with this function:

```
func getTime(startTime:String, startM:String, endTiem: String, endM:String) {

    let date = NSDate();
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
    formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy";

    let dateStrStart = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    var dateStrEnd = ""
    if (startM == "PM" && endM == "AM") {
        let dateEnd = NSDate(timeInterval: 86400, sinceDate: date)
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter();
        formatter.dateFormat = "M/dd/yyyy";

        dateStrEnd = formatter.stringFromDate(dateEnd)
    } else {
        dateStrEnd = dateStrStart
    }

    let RealEndTime = (endTiem + ", " + dateStrEnd);
    let RealStartTime = (startTime + ", " + dateStrStart);
}
```

you just have to grab the AM or PM part. 
And if the `startTime` is PM and the `endTime` is AM then your dateEnd is the `currentDate` plus **one** day.

Comment: Are you sure that you can just get "PM" or "AM" from a string that looks something like example "10:30 AM" because it isn't working.  Do I need to convert the strings into a date then look for AM and PM then convert back to a string?

Comment: Ok so I figured it out. You have to say *** if ((startM.hasSuffix("PM") && EndM.hasSuffix("AM")) *** If you don't do this then it only looks for the strings "PM" and "AM" which doesn't work since that isn't the whole string.  I will edit your answer.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for your help, this answer was very useful to me as well.